# Installing tar.gz when there is no configure file

Tags: games, compiling

I've downloaded a tar.gz for the game Solar 2, and extracted it. Frustratingly, there is no configure file for it, nor is there an INSTALL or a README file. If I skip straight to the "make" command, it tells me there's no targets specified and no makefile found. I'm also having the same problem with another game I've downloaded, NightSky.

Not quite sure how to proceed. I can't find any official documentation or anyone else having these problems. Any suggestions?

Comment: We kinda need to know what's in the file..

Comment: suggest you add the links to these games.

Comment: Seth - How would I go about doing this? Is there a command I can do to get a list of files?

Comment: Foss - I paid for them. It's basically pirating if I share them with you. If it's any help, I got them through the latest Humble Bundle.

Comment: I don't think they should need compiling, just extracting and then installing or running from that folder: see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file?rq=1), but ignore the answers to do with compiling.

Comment: Additionally to what Mik said: if you bought them the seller/author should be able and willing to tell you how to start them.

Comment: @schtocker  Sorry, didn't get your comment.  Add the 'at' sign (@) when you want to get someone's attention ;)  Anyway, you couldn't just upload a picture of Nautilus with the folder open?

Comment: @Seth I just presumed you'd want to see ALL the files, not just the ones at the top of the extracted directory. Here's a direct link to a picture http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/8356/solar2011.png

Comment: Just so everyone knows; I have dropped Humble Bundle Support an e-mail concerning the issue. They are yet to reply though.

Comment: @schtocker  Try running the file called `solar2.sh`.

Comment: @Seth Oh, well that was easy. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot you provided here in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264437/installing-tar-gz-when-there-is-no-configure-file#comment331020_264437), I think you just need to run the file named `solar2.sh` and it will handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Either this actually contains the binaries, or it uses cmake for it's build system. Try going into the directory and typing `cmake .`

Comment: `CMake Error: The source directory "/home/benjamin/Games/Solar2" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

Comment: @schtocker unless it's built with scons (there will be a file called sconscript in there somewhere I think) then this answer is right and your tarball contains the compiled program already. You should be able to run it from it's folder if this is the case.